# Bibliography style: author format

Tags: bibliographies

I would like the item in my bibliography to be format like this

```
Cauchy, L. A., Goursat E., Contour integral. French Academy, 2012.
```

That is:
-no numbering or key before the authors name
-lastname before the firstname where the firstname is abbreviate

But I get this

[image]

with the below sample document which illustrates the different kind of author entries I can have.

Should I manually format all author entries to get the format I want?
Is there an automated way to get this result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{example.bib}

    @article{
        refOne,
        author = {Cauchy, L. A. and E. Goursat },
        title = {Contour integral},
        year = {2012},
        journal = {French Academy},
    }

    @article{
        refTwo,
        author = {Louis Augustin Cauchy and Edouard Goursat},
        title = {Contour integral},
        year = {2012},
        journal = {French Academy},
    }

    @article{
        refThree,
        author = {L. A. Cauchy and E. Goursat},
        title = {Contour integral},
        year = {2012},
        journal = {French Academy},
    }

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \bibliography{example}{}
        \bibliographystyle{plain}
        \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I recommend the package `biblatex`. I think the style `authoryear` is a good starting point. However there are a lot of styles available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the preamble add:

```
    \usepackage[round, sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}
```

and near the end of document

```
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    \bibliography{example}  % example.bib
```

This should have no numbers in the references included.

Comment: You can just give first and last names, and the authors should be fine.

Comment: I try your suggestion, but I get `natbib error: bibliography not compatible with author-year citations`. Should the author name be written in a certain format?

Answer (score 2):

The formatting requirements you report are sufficiently different from most known canned bibliography styles. In consequence, it would require a lot of (rather tedious) work to take an existing bibliography style file and hack it to make it generate references that meet your precise formatting needs.

Fortunately, there's actually no need to embark on this rather tedious path. I would recommend that you run the file [makebst.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/makebst.tex) through LaTeX. (At a command prompt, type "latex makebst" and follow the prompts.) This utility (created by the author of the `natbib` package) poses lots of detailed questions regarding how you want various items formatted, and at the end of the process it creates a brand-new bibliography style (with extension `.bst`) that is tailored to your exact needs.

Separately, you don't mention if you use any citation management packages. If you don't already use such a package, you may want to acquaint yourself with the very widely used [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) package.